# Cannot assign a value of type ViewController to a value of type UITextFieldDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, syntax-error, uitextfielddelegate

Here's the error when I wrote the line `self.MessageTextField.delegate = self`:

> /ChatApp/ViewController.swift:27:42: Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'

Here's my Swift code (ViewerController.swift):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ChatApp
//
//  Created by David Chen on 15/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2015年 cwsoft. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var MessageTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ButtonSend: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var DockViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var MessageTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        self.MessageTableView.delegate = self
        self.MessageTableView.dataSource = self
        //Set delegate
        self.MessageTextField.delegate = self

        self.messagesArray.append("Test 1")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 2")
        self.messagesArray.append("Test 3")
    }

    @IBAction func ButtonSendPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.DockViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK : TextField Delegage Methods


    //MARK : Table View Delegate Methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.MessageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messagesArray.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my pc dead last night, I'll check it tonight. Now I gotta go to school. Thank you for your helpful answer @luk2302. And I'm learning swift by watching a tutorial on YouTube which in a channel called "Learn With Chris" :)

Comment: Xcode should detect this and popup a fix.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The line `self.MessageTextField.delegate = self` causes the error since you try to assign `self` as the `delegate` of a `UITextField`.
But your `ViewController` **is not** a `UITextFieldDelegate`. To make your class this kind of delegte, you need to adopt the [`UITextFieldDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/). This can be achieved by adding it to the list of protocols and classes your class inherits from / conforms to. In your case that is done by changing the line

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Comment: i have the same error. Now added the UITextViewDelegate and the error does not go away... Anyone has a Solution?

Comment: @hannes UITextViewDelegate is something else. The difference is *Field* vs. *View*!

Comment: @luk2302 I read your comment above and it still didn't click what you meant.  I finally figured it out. UITextViewDelegate vs UITextFieldDelegate.  Not the same.

Answer (score 13):

Declare that your class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and implement any of those protocol methods that you need.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but it was because of a different issue:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    let customerCardTableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        table.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.separatorStyle = .none
        table.separatorColor = UIColor(rgb:0xFFFFFF)
        table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

        return table
    }()

    ...other code 
}
```

and I did extend my `CustomViewController` to conform to the `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

The reason was that `self` isn't accessible if you're using `let`. I had to `lazy var customerCardTableView: UITableView` i.e.:

```
lazy var customerCardTableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    table.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    table.separatorStyle = .none
    table.separatorColor = UIColor(rgb:0xFFFFFF)
    table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

    return table
}()
```

`let`s are required to happen during instantiation, but `lazy var`s can be delayed to a time after instantiation, hence they can access `self`...

Answer (score 2):

Embarrassing to own up to it, but worth a mention. Make sure that you're **extending the correct view controller** when declaring conformance. For example, don't do this by accident.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

}

extension SimilarlyNamedViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

It's an easy one to do if you use autocomplete and gets by you because, at a glance, it looks the same.